# Make only child class able to call constructor in java

Tags: java, class, constructor, abstract-class

I want to extend a class A and call the constructor of the class A from the child class B with the super() method. Also should the class A only be instantiated via the child class B. I can do that very simply by making class A abstract. But I read that I should only declare classes abstract, when they have at least one abstract method. Is there another way of making class A only be instantiated by the child class B by calling the super() method?

Comment: Make the constructor `protected`. Then only a child class can invoke it.

Comment: But for that the child class and the parent class need to be in different packages?

Comment: Not true. And package-private doesn't work like that either.

Comment: @StefanB Check out the Tutorial for information on access control https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use abstract if there are certain implementations your child class needs, especially if you don't want the parent class to be instantiated **ever!**

However, in your case, I don't think there are any methods that need to be implemented or inherited, so you can just use *protected*.

Good luck!